# Evento Checked para botão em Cross Platform Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

É possível criar um botão com o evento `Checked` em `Xamarin` ?
Se sim, como fazer ?

Answer (score 0):

tente dessa forma

```
checkbox.Click += (o, e) => {
    if (checkbox.Checked)
        // checkbox selecionado
    else
        // checkbox nao selecionado
};
```

Comment: isso pra um botão ou pra um checkbox ?

Comment: esse é o evento para o check box no caso do botão usa apenas o if dentro do evento do botão

Comment: button.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  if (checkbox.Checked)
        // checkbox selecionado
    else
        // checkbox nao selecionado

 }

Comment: então é que eu precisava fazer com que o botão tivesse o comportamento de um checkbox. Tipo, quando clicar no botão ele afunda quando clicar novamente, volta pro seu estado normal.

Comment: Dessa forma então só manipular o comportamento do botão 
Uma maneira mais fácil não sei se é bem o que você que mais poderia usar o SwitchCell mais fácil 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SwitchCell/